# How is it possible to view the new user and their details?

Tags: support, statistics

I have the privilege for using the **moderation tool** and it has bunch of features like Highest voted, Lowest voted, Most viewed etc., under the stats menu.
But I don't see any features like, **How many users registered today, 2d, 7d, 14d, 30d?** However, I can view the top new user and their details in the User menu.

Does anyone have any idea how to view the new user stats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know of is going to Users - New users, and sorting by Creation Date.  I'm not sure if there are any tools beyound that.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need the moderator tools. You can get all this information through the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

I wrote a [quick query](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/377036/new-users) that will return all the users who created an account with the site in the last 24 hours. As you can see this gives essentially the user profile information for each user. If you wanted the counts separated by days then I could write that query too. This was mostly a proof of concept.

I don't know how comfortable you or the other users are with SQL, but I can extend this and/or add more comments if you are confused. Your best bet would probably be to ask a question over on [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) though if you're looking for anything beyond the basics. They have lots of smart people who could help you out.